# js, не делается JSON.stringify()

Tags: javascript, json, строки, request, response

Я при отправке на back делаю `JSON.stringify({result: {К: 100}})`. Но в `Request payload` он отображается как объект. И в итоге после ответа back я вижу не строку, а `[object Object]`. Как это исправить?

```
send({ result: statistic });
send = async (data) => {
  try {
    await fetch(`url`, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer`,
      },
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
}
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Comment: Дополнил, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: data покажите вашу

Comment: Но этот код по всем законам логики работать не может. Ведь здесь вызов функции идет до её записи по имени `send`.

Comment: Это я условно, он в разных файлах(функция send в другом модуле). Она вызывается правильно, но ложится не строка, а объект.

Comment: Приведенный код работает верно. Если ты получаешь `[object Object]` в данном случае, значит `data` - это уже строка `[object Object]` и надо смотреть места из которых функция вызывается. Самая простая проверка, это добавить строку `console.log(data, JSON.stringify(data))` перед вызовом `fetch` и посмотреть что будет выведено.

Comment: _Но этот код по всем законам логики работать не может._ - вполне может, если использовать нормальные функции, а не стрелочные

Comment: Ваша data точно является объектом?